# How do microservices and 12-factor app principles come together?

Tags: microservices, principles

I'm wondering how service oriented architectures can follow the [12-factor principles](https://12factor.net).

Designing an architecture as microservices means (to me) that you separate the features in services. This means you have multiple code source for the different services.

The first principle of a 12 factor application is "One codebase". So if we have multiple services, we have several codebases and the first principle is broken.

Are the two architectures mutually exclusive or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you [click through](https://12factor.net/codebase) to the full description of the first factor?

> If there are multiple codebases, it’s not an app – it’s a distributed
>   system. Each component in a distributed system is an app, and each can
>   individually comply with twelve-factor.

So when thinking about 12-factor apps in the context of microservices, treat each microservice as a separate app.

Answer (score 2):

Microservices need not be in separate codebases. There shouldn't be shared dependencies, and that's certainly harder to maintain in a single codebase, but it's not prohibitive. Having your various microservices in a single codebase has some advantages like easier code searching, nicer commit atomicity, easier code backups, easier authentication/authorization, easier testing and static analysis... It's generally how I've seen them setup.

Comment: MS don't even need to be implemented with the same stack.

Comment: Curiously, the very same *Codebase* chapter states: *Multiple apps sharing the same code is a violation of twelve-factor. The solution here is to factor shared code into libraries which can be included through the dependency manager.*